# Disable right-click region on Synaptics Touchpad with V19.0.19 driver

Tags: drivers, windows-10, touchpad

The latest version (V19.0.19.1) of the Synaptics Touchpad drivers (SMBus, Windows 10) does not appear to have the option to disable right click functionality when clicking in the lower right portion of the Touchpad - see the attached screenshot.

Does anyone know of maybe a registry entry I can change to disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured out a semi-workaround to get the Control Panel to show the option.

Open regedit and navigate to ...

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPCpl\Controls\02TabClick\1ClickCornerCheckBox`

- Delete the entry named `Visibility`
- Update the entry named `Top` so that it reads `240` in decimal

Now go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPCpl\Controls\02TabClick\1ClickCornerInfoText`

- Delete the entry named `Visibility`
- Update the entry named `Top` so that it reads `240` in decimal

Now the settings show the missing option - see screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution was in the "Clicking" (gear icon) options and is confusingly named "Corner Click Action". Setting it to "Primary Click" is what you want. If you set it to "None" then that area is unclickable.

This is how I did it no mine. Unfortunately every experience is different in the Windows community. This seems to be a "Synaptics ClickPad V1.1 on SMB Port" hardware using "Synaptics Pointing Device - v19.4.3.182 21Mar18" Software. Good luck with yours.
[image]